# date from 3 different variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, concatenation

I have three columns for day ,month and year which I want to use to make one date column

```
> dt
    mon day year
 1:  NA  NA   NA
 2:  NA  NA   NA
 3:  NA  NA   NA
 4:  NA  NA   NA
 5:  NA  NA   NA
 6:  NA  NA   NA
 7:  NA  NA   NA
 8:  10  10 2017
 9:  NA  NA   NA
10:   4   4 2018
11:  NA  NA   NA
12:  NA  NA   NA
13:  NA  NA   NA
14:  NA  NA   NA
15:  NA  NA   NA
16:  NA  NA   NA
>
```

I used below code,its giving strange results:

```
> as.Date(paste(dt$mon,dt$day,dt$year,sep="-"),format = "%m-%d-%y")
 [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
 [8] "2020-10-10" NA           "2020-04-04" NA           NA           NA           NA          
[15] NA
```

I also tried below:

```
library("lubridate")
with(dt, ymd(sprintf('%04d%02d%02d', year, mon, day)))
```

here I am getting error:
Error in sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", year, mon, day) : 
  invalid format '%04d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects

Please suggest if there is anything wrong with these codes or if there is any better solution for my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your year is in 4 digits format.

So you should use %Y

```
as.Date(paste(dt$mon,dt$day,dt$year,sep="-"),format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Comment: I initially had the year variable as factor, different codes for different years. I changed this to numeric , anything I can do when year,month are not numeric?

Answer (score 3):

This is more of an addition to the answer given by @Giovana, but if we concatenate the date using a year-month-day format with dashes, we don't even need to pass a format string to `as.Date`:

```
dt$date <- as.Date(paste(dt$year, dt$mon, dt$day, sep="-"))
```

[Check here](http://rextester.com/FOO39237) for a brief demo using the above logic.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(do.call(paste, dt))
```

If it is a `data.table`

```
dt[, date := anydate(do.call(paste, .SD))]
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between this solution and the great ones already posted is that I tried to mirror the structure you used, keeping `with` and `ymd`, and just fixing the error in getting the string together properly.

```r
library(lubridate)
dt <- data.frame(mon = c(10, 4), day = c(10, 4), year = c(2017, 2018))

with(dt, ymd(paste(year, mon, day, sep = "-")))
#> [1] "2017-10-10" "2018-04-04"
```

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This works! thanks. I was getting error with sprint earlier